# Unable to start multiple Serilog sinks from Asp.net core website hosted in windows service

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-services, serilog

My service runs fine and it is writing to event log serilog sink just fine too. My problem is that serilog refuses to write to any other sink provided in appsettings.json
My **Appsettings.json** snippet

```
 "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.EventLog" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "System": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [

      {
        "Name": "EventLog",
        "Args": {
          "source": "FMS",
          "manageEventSource": true
        }
      },          
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "Args": {

          "pathFormat": "D:\\publish\\log-{Date}.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 1024,
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 60,
          "shared": true,
           "buffered": true
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "WithProcessId", "WithProcessName", "WithExceptionDetails" ]
  }
```

I am setting up my logger in my CustomWebHostService as

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Data.GetDirectoryPath())//gets directory
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        public CustomWebHostService(IWebHost host) : base(host)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
              .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
              .CreateLogger();
        }
```

I have tried creating a console sink and a plain old file sink too, nothing works except the eventlog sink for me. I have updated to the latest stable version of all the required nuget packages.

edit: I've tried and the service CAN write to the location.

Comment: If File sink doesnt work, its typically file permissions - either use SysInternals Filemon to find out whats being denied, or verify by doing a File.WriteAllText to verify where you want to put your log is accessible.

Comment: can you give me some links? filemon seems to have been deprecated and i;ve tried and the service can write to the location where i'm putting the logs

Comment: Unfortunately I dont know the config syntax ;( `RollingFile` is deprecated in favor of File - suggest doing a `WriteTo.File` and seeing if that works (it should if raw file write works) - if it does, you know its down to config ingestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was this line:

```
"Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.EventLog" ],
```

You need to specify all the sinks if you're using this syntax. It can be completely removed and the sinks will work (or you can specify it so you can easily turn sinks off using one line).